# Include array to mongoDB query with group()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to add the paramater sector as an array in the group () statement.

I have the following code:

```
        await Escaneado.aggregate([  
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    { "gestion": id },
                    { "disponible": true }
                ] 
            },
        },    
      
        {
            $group: {
                _id: { 
                    code:"$codigo",
                    quantityTarget:"$cantidadObjetivo",
                },
                quantityTotalScanded : { $sum: "$cantidad" } 
             }
        },
        {
            $addFields:{
                difference:{ $subtract: ["$quantityTotalScanded", "$_id.quantityTarget"]}
            }
         },
    ])
```

output:

```
{
"ok": true,
"escaneadosDB": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "code": "0V3011123A00",
            "quantityTarget": 36
        },
        "quantityTotalScanded": 36,
        "difference": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "code": "0V3011123B00",
            "quantityTarget": 36
        },
        "quantityTotalScanded": 4,
        "difference": -32
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "code": "0V3012121D00",
            "quantityTarget": 56
        },
        "quantityTotalScanded": 56,
        "difference": 0
    }
]}
```

output expected:

```
{
"ok": true,
"escaneadosDB": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "code": "0V3011123A00",
            "quantityTarget": 36,
            "sector": ["A", "B", "C"]
        },
        "quantityTotalScanded": 36,
        "difference": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "code": "0V3011123B00",
            "quantityTarget": 36,
            "sector": ["A"]
        },
        "quantityTotalScanded": 4,
        "difference": -32
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "code": "0V3012121D00",
            "quantityTarget": 56,
            "sector": ["A", "B"]
        },
        "quantityTotalScanded": 56,
        "difference": 0
    }
]}
```

I think I can add it as an array, but i do not know how implement! .

The sectors are different parameters, therefore I cannot use it as "_id". I need total quantity and  the sectors in the query.

How could I do this with mongo?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

add this in group() sentence:

```
sectors: { $push:  { sector: "$sector" } }
```

all code:

```
await Escaneado.aggregate([  
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        { "gestion": id },
                        { "disponible": true }
                    ] 
                },
            },    
          
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: { 
                        code:"$codigo",
                        quantityTarget:"$cantidadObjetivo",
                    },
                    quantityTotalScanded : { $sum: "$cantidad" },
                    sectors: { $push:  { sector: "$sector" } }

                 }
            },
            {
                $addFields:{
                    difference:{ $subtract: ["$quantityTotalScanded", "$_id.quantityTarget"]}
                }
             },
            {$sort: {"cantidadTotal": -1}},
```